# Https getting server certificate

Tags: android, ssl, httpclient

I'm trying for a several days to find out how to get the certificate from a server, we are working on a SSL communication and in order for me to identify the server I need to check its certification.

Few thing about the code, I'm using HttpClient and - I DON'T want to create a key store out of the certification and add it to the "trust store" as [this](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html) link and many other suggesting.

So, what I did in order to get the certification is to implement `X509HostnameVerifier`, and in its verify() method to do:

```
session.getPeerCertificates();
```

but that function through exception:

```
 An exception occurred: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

public class MyHostnameVerifier implements ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        Certificate[] certificates;
        try {
            certificates = session.getPeerCertificates();

            // if connection doesn't contain any certificate - drop it, it might be an hacker.
            if (certificates == null || certificates.length == 1)
                return true;
        } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(String hostname, SSLSocket socket) throws IOException {
        socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates(); // exception
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(String hostname, String[] arg1, String[] arg2) throws SSLException {
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(String arg0, java.security.cert.X509Certificate arg1) throws SSLException {
    }
}
```

and usage example:

```
PoolingClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();

// Increase max total connection to 10
cm.setMaxTotal(GlobalConstants.HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

int timeoutConnection = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS_DEFAULT;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new MyHostnameVerifier();

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
cm.getSchemeRegistry().register(new ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.conn.scheme.Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory));
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParameters);
```

Comment: I think you usually use a custom `TrustManager` in Java. The server's certificate is provided when `TrustManager` methods are called.

Comment: @jww You are absolutely right, I managed to solved this thread and going to publish the solution in the next couple of days.

Comment: would u mind sharing here the solution?

Comment: @RSC I published my solution. I hope that it would be clear, and if you find it useful - please rate it :)

Comment: Thanks Dalvik. So your solution connects via Socket. I also did something similar using sockets and was testing my connection against Main in the Middle attacks and I noticed that if the attacker is using a HTTP proxy (like Fiddler), the socket connection will connect directly to the server (validating then the SSL certificate) while all the http communication will still be caught the attacker (assuming that he was able to install his custom certificate on the user device). Did you face something like that?

Comment: @RSC I'm not sure that I understood your scenario. If the connection is Http we have nothing to do in order to defend yourself against man in the middle attack. If the hacker catch the ssl request with proxy he cannot really do with it anything.

Comment: I meant HTTP Proxy like Fiddler (that only gets HTTP level communication, including HTTPS. It does not capture lower level packet communication as on TCP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys,

Here is the solution,

So first of all you should understand how the TrustManager works, each certified ssl communication is being checked against the TrustManager. Now, defaultly there's the system TrustManager that contains all the already certified certificates(you can find it easily in the Settings).

Next, http communication uses Socket so we need to find a way to connect our TrustManager to the used socket - you can found the implementation below.

So in order to actually get the certificate and compare it to a local hardcoded one you'll need to implement TrustManager.

By the way, I know it's obvious but I'll say it anyway, never save hardcoded passwords/certificates etc.. always save its SHA1/SHA256 in order to fight hacking.

Here is the code:

```
public class X509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private final static String TAG = "X509TrustManager";

private static final boolean DEAFULT_TRUST_ALL_SSL_CONNECTIONS = true;

private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

private boolean trustAllSSLConnections;

/**
 * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
 */
public X509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

    trustAllSSLConnections = DEAFULT_TRUST_ALL_SSL_CONNECTIONS;

    TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    factory.init(keystore);
    TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
    }
    this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
}

/**
 * verified the server certificate
 */
@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {


        X509Certificate certificate = certificates[0];
        byte[] bytes = certificate.getTBSCertificate();

        // Compare your the certificate’s bytes to yours hardcoded certificate.         
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
 */
@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
}
```

}

Usually for every certified request there's a path of certifications, from the top Certification Authority, to other sub-authorities(companies, proxies..), your certificate - that is why your certificate will probably be in the first cell of the array(I'm basing this theory on some tests, not real deep investigation).

In order to connect the TrustManager to the socket use the following code:

```
public class SSLSocketFactory implements LayeredSocketFactory {

private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager(null) }, null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
    if (this.sslcontext == null) {
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    }
    return this.sslcontext;
}

public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

    if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
        // we need to bind explicitly
        if (localPort < 0) {
            localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
        }
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
        sslsock.bind(isa);
    }

    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return sslsock;

}

public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return true;
}

public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
// Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
// for the correct operation of some connection managers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(SSLSocketFactory.class));
}

public int hashCode() {
    return SSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
}
```

}

Now, in order to connect the socket to the HttpClient use this code:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

    params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
    params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE, new ConnPerRouteBean(HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS));


    params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);

    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new SSLSocketFactory(), 443));
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

    ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

    // enable proxy web debugging ("sniffing")
    ProxySelectorRoutePlanner routePlanner = new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(),
            ProxySelector.getDefault());
    client.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

    // disable retries
    client.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false));

    // setup  User-Agent
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, getAppContext());
```

Don't forget to test it against a certified communication.